# Problems Resetting Level Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reset

I have a problem with restarting my level in Unity. I have a UI button that when you click it goes through this line of code:

```css
Application.LoadLevel(1);
```

And for some reason none of the codes run and the scene is just frozen. Thanks in advance please help.

Comment: Do you see any errors or messages in the console? What are the surrounding lines of code? Do you have (at least) two scenes configured in your build settings?

Comment: Did you already put this scene in building configuration list and it is indexed as 1? Also you need to provide some log if there is errors on your console or a little more code because with this single command is impossible to understand if it stuck before or after this call...

Answer (score 2):

When I want to reload my current scene, I use: `Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevelName);`

Another way to see what index your level has in the build is, to go to *File > Build Settings*. In the scene list, the number at the right of the scene will show you what number to insert as a parameter into `Application.LoadLevel()`.